# Number of fields returned by Solr Suggester

Tags: solr, search-suggestion

By the default Solr [Suggester](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/suggester.html) component is returning 3 fields for each of the suggestions:

```
{
    "term": "electronics and computer1",
    "weight": 2199,
    "payload": ""
}
```

Is there a way to extend number of fields returned for each of the suggestions? I would like to have for example additional fields here which I've added to the index (e.g. ID of an index record).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always stuff a number of infoss into a single payload field, separated by some char (like |). Simple, but works.

Comment: Interesting approach, this might solve my issues. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain how did you achieve this? I am in a similar situation and it might help me